# application/json content doesn't get gzip'ed with IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, web.config, compression

We have some rather lengthy AJAX calls in our app, some of which transmit over 100k of data across a rather slow encrypted network.  I'd like to enable G-Zip compression on `application/json` to speed this up a bit.  However, I'm having a tough time!  First, note that the server definitely supports this.  `application/javascript` and `text/*` compress just fine.  The first thing I tried was adding the following to `web.config` in the `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

This had no effect.  I even enabled `"*/*"` on everything just to test.

Next, I dug up the all-powerful `applicationHost.config` file.  This had:

```
<section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

Which I changed to:

```
<section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="Everywhere" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Still no go.  I did an `iisreset` just to make sure the new setting would take effect.

Lastly, I edited the actual `<httpCompression>` section in `applicationHost.config` and manually added in:

```
<add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
```

Well, this actually worked!  However, I feel it's a bit hacky to modify the `applicationHost.config` when I'd rather just enable this for a single web application.  What am I doing wrong and why can't I override this in `web.config`?  Thanks!